# Find Key / Value in Object (list comprehension?)

Tags: javascript

How to do find `index==2` in JS?

```
myObj = {
  policy : {
            index: 1,
            page : "/summer"
         },
  purchase : {
            index: 2,
            page : "/sun"
         }
}
```

E.g.

```
for (var key in myObj) {
  if (myObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    if (myObj[key].index === 2)
       console.log("Found.");
  }
}
```

How to do this in JS more efficiently?

Comment: The same as how you do in js

Comment: That is hugely dissapointing. So the argument "TypeScript took a lot from CoffeeScript" was a blatant lie?

Comment: who ever said typescript took a lot from CofeeScript? It's a javascript superset. If anything it's closer to C#. :P You can always add lodash and use that (with type inference). :)

Comment: "TypeScript took a lot from CoffeeScript". TS is javascript superset why would it take something from totally different language like coffeescript?

Comment: Superset, Mooperset. If you think TypeScript did not take the double arrow from CoffeeScript you are wrong. CS transpiler was dev's choice transpiler in Angular1 and TS transpiler is dev's choice in Angular2.  http://de.slideshare.net/NeilGreen1/type-script-vs-coffeescript-vs-es6

Comment: @StephanKristyn you mean the arrow function? That was implemented because it's in ES6 and TS is a superset of that. ES6 was probably influenced by coffeescript so transitively you could maybe say that; however, it's something that's existed in other languages before coffeescript existed—like C#.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Javascript-wise I'd use the [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) function:

```
Object.keys(myObj).forEach(key => {
    if (myObj[key].index === 2) {
        console.log("Found.");
    }
});
```

Because it removes the need to check `myObj.hasOwnProperty(key)`.

If you want to stop the search when one was found:

```
Object.keys(myObj).some(key => myObj[key].index === 2);
```

Answer (score 13):

Use `Array.find`:

```
Object.keys(myObj).find(k => myObj[k].index === 2)
```

This will return the key in which the match occurred.