# Cypress: cy.window(): Unable to get property values

Tags: cypress

**Goal**

Hello, I wish to gather custom property values for a `window` object of a page using [cy.window()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/window.html).

**Issue**

When using [cy.log()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/log.html) jointly with `JSON.stringify()`, it presents that it does have properties with values; however, when using lodash `_.has()`, does not have these properties and thereby no value because these properties are not found.

**Code**

The following Cypress custom command using [cy.window()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/window.html) gathers custom window's property

```
export function cmdCypressWindow($propName: string) {
  cy.window()
    .its($propName)
    .then(($propValue: Cypress.AUTWindow) => {
      cy.log('props names:', JSON.stringify(Object.getOwnPropertyNames($propValue), null, 2));
      cy.log('props values:', JSON.stringify($propValue, null, 2));
      cy.log('VERSION prop:', _.has($propValue, 'VERSION'));
      cy.log('HOST prop:', _.has($propValue, 'HOST'));
      cy.log('VERSION value:', _.get($propValue, 'VERSION'));
      cy.log('HOST value:', _.get($propValue, 'HOST'));
    });
}
```

Passed in for parameter `$propName` value **`'ACT'`**, because I am expecting the page's window object to contain **`window.ACT["VERSION"]`**.

Using the example code, the log output shows that the page's window does contain property **`ACT["VERSION"]`**.

However, when accessing this window object, listed properties are unavailable and undefined:

```
window
- its   .ACT
log     props names:, [ "__esModule", "VERSION", "HOST", "RulesList", "RulesAddEdit", "AppsList", "AppsOAuth", "AppsAdd" ]
log     props values:, { "VERSION": "0.2.11", "HOST": "radmin" }
log     VERSION prop:, false
log     HOST prop:, false
log     VERSION value:
log     HOST value:
```

How do I resolve this? Thank you, all feedback is very much appreciated.

Comment: 'ACT' is a property the app has defined on window? What does the code for that look like?

Comment: Have you tried using `Cypress._` instead of importing lodash?

Comment: Thank you, I will check out that suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Found part of the solution here:
[TypeScript: Find Key / Value in Object (list comprehension?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38292652/typescript-find-key-value-in-object-list-comprehension)

Modified the function:

```
export function cmdCypressWindow($propName: string) {

  cy.window()
    .its($propName)
    .then(($propValue: Cypress.AUTWindow) => {
      const actValues: Record<string, string> = {};

      Object.keys($propValue).forEach(key => {
        // @ts-ignore
        if (typeof $propValue[key] !== 'function') {
          // @ts-ignore
          actValues[key as string] = $propValue[key];
        }
      });

      cy.log(`window.${$propName}`, JSON.stringify(actValues, null, 2));

      cy.wrap(actValues);
    });
}
```

Results show that I was able to acquire values from `window` object:

```
log   props names:, [ "__esModule", "VERSION", "HOST", "RulesList", "RulesAddEdit", "AppsList", "AppsOAuth", "AppsAdd" ]
log   window.ACT, { "VERSION": "0.2.11", "HOST": "radmin" }
wrap  {version: 0.2.11, host: radmin}
```